# As a developer how can i make the update for my unity game not upload the entire game again?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

So, I published a Unity game on google play store. Every time I want to update it I need to upload the whole apk 27mb. What can I do to only upload like 2 mb as the new update? Because Unity produces a new apk everytime I change something.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to upload a whole new APK.

If you want to only change content, you can create an APK of just the core of the game and have the game download expansion files.

[APK Expansion Files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Comment: AND WILL THE USERS DOWNLOAD ONLY THE DIFFERENCES OR THE WHOLE NEW APK ?

Comment: Thank you so much.. am gonna try that out.